# volley display previous fragment response in new fragment when replacing previous fragment to new fragment via navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley, fragmenttransaction

i have a total 12 fragment in navigation drawar.. each fragment has volley method.
and each fragment display its own volley response except position = 1 and position = 5 fragment.

when my app start

**Scenario 1:**  i open position 1 fragment and after i open position 5 fragment than both fragment has position 1 fragment response.

**Scenario 2:** if i open position 5 fragment and after open position 1 fragment than both fragment has position 1 fragment response.

**Scenario 1 images:**

[image: FragmentInbox]
[image: FragmentLaws]

**Scenario 2 images:**

[image: FragmentLaws]
[image: FragmentInbox]

My fragment transaction method class:

```
private void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    llContainer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    if (fragment != null) {
        llContainer.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment frag = null;
    switch (position) {
        case POS_HOME:
            frag = FragmentHome.instance(screenTitles[position]);
            break;
        case POS_INBOX:
            txtToolbarTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txtToolbarTitle.setText("Notifications");
            frag = FragmentInbox.instance(screenTitles[position]);
            break;
        case POS_LOG:
            frag = FragmentLog.instance(screenTitles[position]);;
            break;
        case POS_BOOK:
            frag = FragmentBook.instance(screenTitles[position]);
            break;
        case POS_BUILDING:
            frag = FragmentBuilding.instance(screenTitles[position]);
            break;
        case POS_LAWS:
            frag = FragmentLaws.instance();
            break;
        case POS_DOCUMENT:
            frag = FragmentDocument.instance(screenTitles[position]);
            break;
        case POS_EVENT:
            frag = FragmentEvent.instance(screenTitles[position]);
            break;
        case POS_BOARD:
            frag = FragmentBoard.instance(screenTitles[position]);
            break;
        case POS_AROUND:
            frag = FragmentAround.instance(screenTitles[position]);
            break;
        case POS_PROFILE:
            frag = FragmentProfile.instance(screenTitles[position]);
            break;
        case POS_CONCIERGE:
            frag = FragmentConcierge.instance(screenTitles[position]);
            break;
    }

    showFragment(frag);
    mSlideMenu.closeMenu();
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell us which fragment corresponds to which position

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in viewPagers, in both fragment viewpager has same id. So i just change fragmentInbox's viewpager id, and its working now.